# Is there any regulation on how much shock a checked-in baggage can receive when traveling by plane?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, fragile-luggage

Is there any regulation on how much [shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_(mechanics)) a checked-in baggage can receive when traveling by plane? If not, do some airports/airlines have some commitments or guidelines on it?

Comment: I would guess "no" and "no", respectively.

Comment: Related on [aviation.se]: [What level of G-force does our body experience when we are traveling in a passenger plane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21902/3427)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you, interesting link! https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=G-force&oldid=878819872#Typical_examples has a few g-force upper bounds as well. Just to clarify: I'm also interested in the shock absorbed at the airport (e.g., loading/unloading baggage to/from the plane).

Comment: Well, no such regulation could bind the laws of physics.  Are you trying to estimate the chance of damage to some fragile item?  Then you really want empirical data, not regulations.  Are you hoping for a rule like "if shock exceeds X G, I will automatically be entitled to compensation?" It doesn't work that way - you would have to demonstrate that your item was actually damaged, and hope that it wasn't something the airline considers "fragile", for which they would normally disclaim liability.

Comment: @NateEldredge One could use a  [shock data logger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_and_vibration_data_logger). I'm just trying to estimate how much protection I need to add for some items, and whether one can get partly reimbursed in some situation.

Comment: Depends if the baggage handlers drop it or not...

Comment: @Doc: well the point would be to quantify the max authorized drop. A video of baggage dropping could be another piece of evidence if such regulations/commitments exist.

Comment: https://spotsee.io/impact for a way to detect shocks on your luggage